# Controlling Different Rotational Speed Of Two Interacting Objects

Tags: animation

[enter link description here](https://vimeo.com/229033521)I have a problem modeling a Geneva Gear with two rotating parts, a cam which is driving a spur gear. The cam rotates continually, but the spur gear rotates by the action of the cam. I either need to slow down the rotation of the spur gear or make it interactive with the cam. BTW, I'm a noob.

Please download Blender file and run animation. I am not going to render the animation. It's fine the way it is.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: See https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use drivers to achieve this. Here is a demonstration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajMAvKRCTBg

Have fun!

Comment: Please do not post answers that rely solely on links.  See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2383/38953